# How to Release audio record when other app request permission which is running in foreground android

Tags: android, audio, audio-recording, foreground, android-audiorecord

I am trying to release audioRecorder in android app when other app like google now, Sound recorder, etc,. request mic permission which has been launched by the user. In some mobiles its showing log that the mic is busy with the status -38 and a popup showing like "This App will not work now". 
If other app request permission the status is -3 but i cant able to detect this status.

Can anyone tell me how to release the Audio recorder ? 
Help Appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer?